# How to add additional classes to a pre-trained object detection model and train it to detect all of the classes (pre-trained + new)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

I had followed this blog --> https://medium.com/@teyou21/training-your-object-detection-model-on-tensorflow-part-2-e9e12714bdf , and built a SSD Mobilenet model which is pre-trained on the COCO Dataset called "ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_coco".

What happens here is that it perfectly detects my new classes, but I want to include the pre-trained classes as well.

I tried changing the number of classes to 96 ( 90 pre-trained + 6 new ) and edited the "labelmap.pbtxt" with the name and corresponding id of all labels from the COCO Dataset with the new classes being added at the last from ids 91 - 96.

It still detects only the new classes only.

What should I do to detect both the pre-trained and new classes?

Comment: I cannot seem to find a definitive answer to this question either.  Any luck?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't. The denses layers who do the classification are trained to output specifics classes. You can't expect the network to ouput classes it didn't see during the training.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how you use the pre trained weights:

1. Use for transfer learning (I think in the link you send this is what they do)
2. Use has a starting point for fitting the entire model.

The first option only trains the detection head and not the backbone of the network - This means that the backbone weights are sherd between your model and the original model.

In the second option you train all the network, backbone + detection head- This means that you have two different models

If in your case you use the second option then the only way to do what you want is to load both networks and run inference on the image once with the original network and second with your new network. Then you combine your results.

If you use the first option then you could do the following:

1. Train the network on your data and save the new detection head weights.
2. Create a new network that has the same backbone but two detection heads:
   one with the original weights and the second head with the new weights.

The idea is that because the backbone is the same for both we can use the backbone to extract the features for the image and then feed each detection head with the features.

This is a tutorial on how to extract weights from one graph and combine them in a new one (This is for TF1) [TensorFlow: saving/restoring and mixing multiple models](https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-saving-restoring-and-mixing-multiple-models-c4c94d5d7125)

Here you can read on how to save and restore part of a model - [save-and-restore-a-subset-of-variables](https://ireneli.eu/2018/07/13/tensorflow-08-save-and-restore-a-subset-of-variables/)